# How to keep keyboard open in iOS and Android from Ionic 3 (Button click after text input)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an ion-input and button next to it(like entering chat in chat apps). When I am hitting the button the keypad keeps closing, I need it to be open until the user clicks on the hardware back button twice / clicking on other focus areas.

```
<ion-input id="inputID" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" type="text" [(ngModel)]="replyMessage"
  (press)="onPastePress($event,message, showSelect)" placeholder="Type a message"></ion-input>
<button for="inputID" (click)="sendMessage()" [attr.disabled]="replyMessage==''?'':null" type="button">
  <!-- <ion-icon></ion-icon> -->
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 14px;">
    send
  </i>
</button>
```

Software details:
Using ionic - 3.20.1
Android version - @8+
iOS version - @5+

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keyboard Plugin to keep your keyboard open:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/keyboard/

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

...

this.keyboard.show();

this.keyboard.hide();
```